# Failing a class senior year undergrad - applying to grad schools

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am currently a senior during my undergraduate degree in biology. I have also just applied to do my masters in public health. However, during my junior year I suffered from a subdural hematoma, and still have concussion symptoms from it (which I have mentioned in my statement of purpose briefly) and these symptoms have impacted me and I fear that I missed up my chances of getting into grad school. Prior, to the fall my gpa was very strong and it dropped during the semester of the fall, however it has been picking back up after the fall. I took a high level biology course this semester and unfortunately was not able to do well in it due to ongoing headaches. I did very well in other lab courses I took, and my gpa is high, but I completely bombed this course and failed it. It is an upper division biology course.
My LOR's are strong, I have medical and healthcare experience (2+) years, and am also an undergraduate researcher at the moment, which I have included in my application for grad schools.
Did this one course mess up my chances of getting into grad schools since it is during my senior year and right before i go into grad school?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say with certainty since the course is in your major. However, you have a valid explanation for the issue and if you have mentioned the medical condition somewhere it should be ok, given that you have strong letters to support your success.

Make sure that your medical condition is fixed, however, and that you can assure people if asked that this won't be an issue in the future.

If this is for the US educational system, there is an opportunity at the start of the program to cover a deficit in the course.

I wonder, however, if you can have the grade expunged, given the medical condition. It might be worth an ask.

(A family member has just this issue applying for undergraduate and decided to delay a year to assure he won't be disadvantaged.)

Comment: Delaying a year seems too over-the-top for this issue,  imo

Comment: @DavidRaveh, Agree, unless the time is needed to recover health, as is the case I mention.